# Android: Unable to launch the contact application in Android Lollipop version

Tags: contacts, android-5.0-lollipop

Recently updated my Device to latest Android Lollipop version. When I try to launch the contact app from my other application, it fails to do so and crashes.

Here is the code that worked for me pre Android L version:

```
Intent intent = getIntent().setComponent( null ).setPackage("com.android.contacts" );
startActivity( intent );
```

All the required permissions are assigned to app in the manifest and I am able to launch the contact app in KitKat and below.

Later I checked with the below code and it launched the contact app:

```
Intent intent = getIntent().setComponent( null ).setPackage("com.google.android.contacts" );
startActivity( intent );
```

Any idea if the package name is changed to something else in Android L?

Comment: Post the logcat.
More over package name of Contacts app in stock L is still `com.google.android.contacts`

Comment: Thanks Nikola. Earlier till kitkat package name was com.android.contacts. So do you mean to say that this is changed in the Android L version as compared to the Kitkat version? Moreover, I checked in the simulator for android L and seems like it is using thee default package name for the contact app i.e com.android.contacts.  could you please confirm this. Reference links will be well appreciated :)

Comment: After a detailed analysis, just came to know that the package name change is nexus specific only and not for other devices